# Maphilight change Image src keeping same map

Tags: jquery, image

We are using maphighlight Jquery to highlight map area on some image.
On button click we would like to load diffrent image src keeping the area map same.

I am able to load different image src, but soon after Map area highlighting stop functioning

Does any one have faced similar problem? Need some help to fix this issue.

This is the existing code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.maphilight.min.js")"></script>

<div id="image1">
<img id="image1id" alt="ABCD" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/A.png")" 
style="box-shadow: #999 0px 0px 15px;" usemap="#a1" />

</div>

<map name="a1">
<area id="aSys" shape="poly" coords="330,145,475,115,475,350,330,367" onclick="Common_dialog();"
                alt="image" title="A SYS" />
 </map>

<button type="button" value="Change" onclick="Common_dialog();">Change</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.map').maphilight(strokeColor = "5C5C5C", fillColor = "5C5C5C", strokeWidth  "1", fillOpacity = "0.4");

    alert("entered11");
});

function Common_dialog(e) {
    var divElements = document.getElementById("image1").innerHTML;
    var updatedDiv = divElements.replace("A.png", "B.png");
    document.getElementById("image1").innerHTML = updatedDiv;
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: I would imagine it's something to do with overwriting `.innerHTML directly`. What about setting a `src` using JQuery for that image instead?

Comment: Yes we have tried setting src  $('#image1id').attr('src', 'B.png'); but getting same issue.

Comment: Would you be able to knock up a fiddle example?

Comment: No I dont have fiddle example for this.

Comment: How about adding `$('.map').maphilight(strokeColor = "5C5C5C", fillColor = "5C5C5C", strokeWidth  "1", fillOpacity = "0.4");` to the end of `Common_dialog` function?

Comment: After adding following code another image B.png is not replaced.  $('.map').maphilight(strokeColor = "5C5C5C", fillColor = "5C5C5C", strokeWidth "1", fillOpacity = "0.4");

Comment: Only issue/problem that we are facing is after another image is loaded Map Area which is highlighted by 'poly'(document.ready). only Map area highlight stops functioning.

Comment: You would get more help with this if you created a Fiddle example.

Comment: maybe try re running the map highlighter script inside of the Common_dialog function. Just for testing. maphighlight might be figuring that its job is done after doc ready and so does not execute on the button click.. hard to tell though. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)